# How to pass notification.userinfo from PushNotification to a specific viewcontroller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have code like this.
if I receive a pushnotification and I tap on it I want to redirect to specific viewcontroller but I want to pass a value (hidden inside notification) to a specific view controller

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive, response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
    {

        LocalData.indexTabBar = nil
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if LocalData.emailLogin != nil && LocalData.passwordLogin != nil && LocalData.tokenLogin != nil {

            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainControllerIfSavedLogin") as! UITabBarController

                      initialViewController.selectedIndex = 2 //Selecting tab here
                      self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

     } else{

         let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as UIViewController

                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

          }

            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }

  completionHandler()
  }
```

Comment: `UNNotificationContent` has a `userInfo` property, other `title` properties, and this can be obtained from `UNNotificationResponse`'s `notification` property. This can be set in the push notification payload.

Answer (score 0):

Get it with

```
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
```

Then send it

```
let tab =  ------ as! MainControllerIfSavedLogin
let vc =  tab.viewControllers!.first as! LoginViewController  
vc.info = userInfo
```

---

```
class LoginViewController : UIViewController {
   var info:[String:Any]?
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks but there's another problem... before "LoginController" there is a TabbarController